# CSS how to make a text extend over a div without resizing it and without rollbars

Tags: html, css

I have a homepage layout with 3 columns with an images and captions inside everyone.
I have a subtitle also, and I want the subtitle extends orizzontally over the div without resizing it and without rollbars.

see a screenshot here: http://www.alessandroboselli.it/foto/screenshot.jpg

and here is the involved CSS code:

```
.homepageimage {
position:relative;
float:left; /* optional */  
top:40px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#5f5f5f')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#5f5f5f');
}

.homepageimage a {
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}

.homepageimage a .homepageimagetitle {
display: block;
font-family: 'Molengo', Arial, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: none;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 0.050em;
word-spacing: 0em;
line-height: 1.2;
padding: 10px 0;
background: #111;
filter:alpha(opacity=75);
opacity:.75;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
width: 190px;
/*position: absolute;
right: 20px;
bottom: 20px;
filter:alpha(opacity=65);
opacity:.65;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)"; /*--IE 8 Transparency--*/
}

.homepageimage a .homepageimagesub {
display: block;
font-family: 'Buda', serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: none;
text-decoration: underline;
text-transform: none;
letter-spacing: 0.007em;
word-spacing: 0em;
line-height: 1.15;
padding: 10px 0;
background: #111;
filter:alpha(opacity=75);
opacity:.75;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 215px;
left: 0px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
overflow: visible;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow

**EDIT:**

The element that is overflowing must have it's width specified. This should set you in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/2qWYf/2

**EDIT #2:**

If you want it to match that link, try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/2qWYf/4/

Comment: no, not working and was already made that try, maybe you didn't read the code I posted

Comment: There is no overflow property in the "code" that you posted.  If you want text to flow out of a div without resizing or scrollbars you need to use the overflow property.  You must also specify a width.

Comment: I already tried posting the overflow property in any of the involved classes with no results, where I need to put it in your opinion, the class of the subtitle or the main block class?

Comment: Need more details, you didn't even post the HTML or an example (JSFiddle or Live).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2qWYf/1/ here it is, the class I want to overflow the div is "homepageimagesub" and also would like that the background "shapes" the text like in this one: http://www.berbere.it/ Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have hard time believing that this is what OP wants to achieve as it just looks broken.. but i guess we'll see.

Comment: Yes tahnks! exactly what I was looking for, but how also to make the background of the text really surround the whole text only and not a  rectangle. See this example: http://www.berbere.it/

Answer (score 0):

Forget "overflow" and just add any width to `.homepageimagesub`

for example:

```
width: 400px;
```

If you want different sizes.. you of course need to add these width's individually.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qWYf/3/

for the sake of making it proper.. you might want to control the width of the `#side-left` and `#side-right` elements as they are parent elements of `.homepageimagesub` elements and control their width.

About proper.. You currently have duplicate `ID's` and thats not proper markup. Basic rule is to use `class` instead of `id` whenever you have more than one element with the same name.